# why restricted isometry property constant $\delta_{2k}<\sqrt{2}-1$?

Tags: compressive-sensing

It's said that $\delta_{2k} < \sqrt{2} -1$ , the solution of the $l_{1}$ problem is that of $l_{0}$ problem.

I checked the proof of $||x^{*}-x||_{l_{2}}\leq C_{0}s^{-1/2}||x-x_{s}||_{l_{1}}+C_{1}\epsilon$

in [this file](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/RIP.pdf) but I haven't found out where the $\sqrt{2}-1$ works.

So it will be very helpful if anyone could tell me if I missed something in that paper or direct me to some relevant literature or give me some tips.

Comment: Welcome. Could you please share how far you did check the proof?

Comment: Thanks very much, I tried to write the proof briefly and found that the inequality implicitly requires  $1-\frac{\sqrt{2}\delta_{2k}}{1-\delta_{2k}}>0$ which is excatly $\delta_{2k}<\sqrt{2}-1$.